# Windows 7 won't start up

Tags: windows-7, boot

Can anyone help me fix my problem? My laptop has a windows 7 os and it won't start, and it has an status code of 0xc00000e9. I'm looking for system repair after the bios boot but there is not. It also won't boot on safe mode. How can I fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already fixed this. I just insert a bootable windows 7 usb and boot it. Then on the installation option click on the repair your computer, then click startup repair and it will automatically detect and fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can select your own answer, you know.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this out, I experienced a problem similar to this before:

1. Make sure the PC is not plugged in the charger.
2. Take out the battery.
3. Take out the harddrive.
4. Wait 10 Seconds, then plug the harddrive back in, then the battery.
5. Power it on.

What this does is drain the electrical reserves inside the MB, or atleast that is what I read when I got the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on a Windows 7 32 bit system ("and herein lies the rub", WS) after swapping RAM sticks (two pairs of identical 4GB sticks).  Repair was unable to restore the situation.

Basically, i had a 32bit system and installing a 64bit version was the only process that worked for me.

[This is my complete solution](https://superuser.com/a/1171587/156771)